# Audit Log in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have admin and subadmin concept in my site and i want to keep track of insertion,updation and deletion performed by the respective users.

Comment: Flagged as it's not a real question but more of a statement on how your site works with no clear definition of what you want help with.

Comment: I mentioned in my description that i want to maintain the audit log.How can i keep track of which insertion,updation and deletion queries are performed by users of the site.

Comment: No, you said "Audit Log in Codeignitor". I could say "Land on the moon" but it wouldn't tell anyone I wanted to know how do it .. A proper question would be "How to enable an audit log in codeignitor". Just saying this so you can get the actual information you are looking for.

Comment: Please advise me the solution for my problem.I am new to this field.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes I have tried this by extending the core database driver and try to redefine query function in my class but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have them write down their actions in a notepad.

---OR----

Check http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html

You can port over some/all of the Profiler.php code to a custom library that you include on interaction pages. Use this library to collect queries and stuff and insert that stuff into the db. Include the library in the constructor of pages you want to audit.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Profiling will track all queries executed but i just need log to be maintained for insert,update or delete queries.

Comment: OK so when you port over the profiler code, just port over the stuff you need.